# Если класс со статик переменной включить в несколько единициц трансляции, может ли быть какое то UB со статик переменной? multiple inclusion

Tags: c++

```
UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    inline static int age; //??
public:
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();
    

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned


public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
private:
    void PrintLogs();

};
```

Comment: Для начала эта строчка вообще не компилируется.

Comment: Самое плохое, что может случиться - это если сделать переменную `inline` и заинклудить в несколько разных .dll, то в каждом будет своя копия переменной.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а возможно как то избежать копирования переменной?

Comment: Не делать inline, вместо этого положить определение в .cpp-файл.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat благодарю.